# Keeping a reference to the Parent in View Controller Containment

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uikit

Consider a basic UIViewController, contained in a UINavigationController or a UITabBarController.  This view controller has a reference to its container, with either:

```
self.navigationController
self.tabBarController
```

Now consider the basic example of View Controller Containment without a Navigation Controller or Tab Bar Controller:

```
[self addChildViewController: child];
[[child view] setFrame: [[self view] bounds]];
[[self view] addSubview: [child view]];
[child didMoveToParentViewController: self];
```

If I want the child view controller to have a reference to the container, what's the best method for doing that?

My guess is that I would do something like this in the child:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) MyContainerController *container;
```

and set it at the same time I'm adding the child to the parent, like so:

```
[child setContainer: self];
```

Is this correct?

I want to ensure that I can reference the container from the child, but I'm also concerned about memory issues.  I believe a strong property would prevent ARC from releasing the child, even if I remove it from the container.  Is that assumption correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have that reference with self.parentViewController. There's no need to create your own. Have a look at the "Getting Other Related View Controllers" section of the UIViewController class reference.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED TO SWIFT 3**

In Swift, the name has changed to `self.parent` which returns a UIViewController optional.